# Replace the first element of a grid with other widget

Tags: flutter, dart, grid

I need help replacing the first element of the StaggeredGridView with other Widget, say, Container. I have been trying to change it for hours but couldn't find a way.

```
       Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                itemCount: posts.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Post post = posts[index];
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage(post.imageUrl),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                    new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 3 : 2),
              ),
            ),
```

Above is the code for the grid I am using. [image: The design that I want.]
[image: The design I am getting.]

Thank you.

Comment: The first picture is the design I need. The second one is what I am getting for now.

Answer (score 0):

`itemBuilder` will generate a widget with the function provided, thus you could just add an `if statement` to build one or other widget:

```dart
itemCount: posts.length + 1, // added one item on the beginning
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  if (index == 0) {
    return Container(
      child: // your widget
    );
  } else {
    Post post = posts[index - 1]; // remember that you have +1 on your index
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(post.imageUrl),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
},
```